# Java Script: How to check if value is number with typeof operator

Tags: javascript, operators

How do I check in the if statement if _energyLevel is a number?
I need to use the typeOf operator for that.
Thanks for your help :)

```
const robot = {
  _model: '1E78V2',
  _energyLevel: 100,
    get energyLevel(){
      if(this._energyLevel === typeof(number)){
        return `My current energy level is ${_energyLevel}`
      }else{

      }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`typeof` operator is applied whose type you want to find. In your case it will go with `this._energyLevel` and `typeof` returns type as string.**

so better code will be

```js
const robot = {
    _model: '1E78V2',
    _energyLevel: 100,
    get energyLevel() {
        if (typeof this._energyLevel === "number") {
            return `My current energy level is ${this._energyLevel}`
        } else {
            return 'Low battery'
        }
    }
};

console.log(robot.energyLevel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you did with the `number` variable, you can achieve same with `_energyLevel`variable:

```
if(typeof(this._energyLevel) === typeof(number)){
```

Comment: Ahhhhh i didn't use the typeof in the first part of the if statement.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that helps

```
 var value = 11;
 if (typeof value == 'number') {
    // is a number
 } else {
    // is not a number
 }
```